# Modificar elementos do array

Tags: java, sql, array, jdbc

Necessito criar uma *query* com a inserção de várias linhas.

1. Alterar um array/list:

> arrayOriginal=[10,20,30,40]
>     valorChave=999

2. O retorno deve ser:

> arrayNovo=[(valorChave,10),(valorChave,20),(valorChave,30),(valorChave,40)]

3. Este será complemento de uma *query* para inserção de várias linhas em uma tabela:

```sql
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES + '${arrayNovo}';
```

O que tentei mas não está funcionando:

```java
String[] novosCodigosArray = codigos;

for(int i = 0; i < novosCodigosArray.length; i++)
    novosCodigosArray[i] = "("+chave+","+novosCodigosArray[i]+")";
return Arrays.toString(novosCodigosArray);

// depois utilizo desta maneira para fazer query
String meuINSERT= "INSERT INTO dbo.tabela";
meuINSERT= meuINSERT +" (col_codigo, col_chave)";
meuINSERT= meuINSERT +" VALUES ";
meuINSERT= meuINSERT + novosCodigosArray;

return meuINSERT;
```

Qualquer ajuda será muito bem-vinda.

Comment: Não vou poder responder agora, mas isto um sério problema de segurança.

Comment: Porque  você não montar sua  query no loop? E retornar uma string?

Comment: Outra coisa para cada nova linha no insert deve ter uma vírgula separado.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, que concatenar `String`s para criar consultas SQL deste jeito é muito perigoso, pois abre o seu sistema para um problema de segurança conhecido como [injeção de SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Fazer isso é uma má-prática de programação, pois no caso de concatenar `String`s, um hacker ou usuário mal-intencionado que tiver controle sobre um dos valores concatenados (por exemplo, algum campo de formulário que ele preencheu), ao colocar um *quote* (`'`) e adicionar fragmentos de SQL neste campo, o usuário mal-intecionado conseguirá alterar a estrutura do seu SQL, podendo até achar um jeito de colocar um `DROP DATABASE` lá no pior caso.

Para resolver este problema (ou possível problema) de injeção de SQL é que o Java dispõe do [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). Outras linguagens de programação também apresentam este conceito.

Por fim, como você parece querer fazer várias inserções em lote, o melhor é usar o mecanismo de *batch*. Para isso, peguei a ideia emprestada [desta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2467152/540552). Dito isso, então acho que essa seria a sua solução:

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MeuDAO {
    private static final String URL = ...;
    private static final String LOGIN = ...;
    private static final String SENHA = ...;

    public MeuDAO() {
    }

    private static final String SQL_INSERT =
            "INSERT INTO tabela (col_codigo, col_chave) VALUES (?, ?)";

    public Connection obterConexao() {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, LOGIN, SENHA);
    }

    public void fazMeuInsert(int chave, int[] valores) {
        if (valores.length == 0) return;
        try (
            Connection conn = obterConexao;
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT))
        ) {
            ps.setInt(1, chave);
            for (int valor : valores) {
                ps.setInt(2, valor);
                ps.addBatch();
            }
            ps.executeBatch();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // Tratar o erro adequadamente.
            // Ou então relançar a exceção declarando "throws SQLException".
            // Ou então encapsular em uma outra exceção e lançá-la.
        }
    }
}
```

Observe que uma vez que a sua SQL é uma `String` monolítica, logo não é possível fazer-se injeção de SQL. Além disso note que devido ao uso do mecanismo do [*try-with-resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) do Java 7 ou superior, não precisamos fechar o `PreparedStatement` e o `Connection` explicitamente. Além disso, o código acima garante que a sua SQL só precisará ser interpretada uma única vez ao invés de uma vez para cada inserção. Além disso apenas uma conexão será aberta no início e fechada no final, ao invés um monte de conexões sendo abertas e fechadas em seguida. Por fim, todas elas serão efetivadas juntas. Tudo isso garante um desempenho e um consumo de rede bem melhor do que seria ao inseri-las uma-a-uma.

Se o seu *array* for muito grande (tipo, milhares de elementos), talvez você queira dividi-lo em lotes para não ficar um *batch* muito grande (que pode consumir muita memória tanto no cliente quanto no servidor). Aqui vai o código que divide automaticamente o *array* em lotes de 1000 elementos:

```
public void fazMeuInsert(int chave, int[] valores) {
    if (valores.length == 0) return;
    try (
        Connection conn = obterConexao;
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT))
    ) {
        int i = 0;
        ps.setInt(1, chave);
        for (int valor : valores) {
            ps.setInt(2, valor);
            ps.addBatch();
            i++;
            if (i % 1000 == 0 || i == valores.size() {
                ps.executeBatch();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // Tratar o erro adequadamente.
            // Ou então relançar a exceção declarando "throws SQLException".
            // Ou então encapsular em uma outra exceção e lançá-la.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agradeço a resposta, porém, não posso usar esta estrutura java dentro da ferramenta que estou trabalhando. A conexão com SQL é realizada separadamente. Devo ter um script para cada item, logo tenho que encontrar um método alternativo. Com array não é possível, certo?

Comment: @Fabi Publiquei uma outra resposta. E sim, com array é posssível e bem fácil de fazer inclusive. Só não sei se entendi direito o que você quer.

Answer (score 2):

Ignorando a questão de segurança e supondo que você tem o Java 8, pode fazer a geração de tuplas SQL em praticamente um comando:

```
Arrays.stream(arrayOriginal)
    .map(v -> String.format("(%d,'%s')", chave, v))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

A primeira linha converte o array num *stream*. A segunda mapeia cada valor formatando a tupla conforme foi definido. A terceira linha pega o resultado e junta tudo numa string separando os itens por um espaço em branco.

Obviamente você pode ajustar cada passo do processo para suas necessidades.

Código completo:

```
int chave = 999;
String[] arrayOriginal = {"10", "20", "30", "40"};
String resultado = Arrays.stream(arrayOriginal).map(v -> String.format("(%d,'%s')", chave, v)).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(resultado);
```

Saída:

> (999,'10') (999,'20') (999,'30') (999,'40')

Answer (score 1):

Bem, considerando que você conheça os perigos de injeção de SQL e tenha certeza que isso não é um risco para você, e que você precise necessariamente gerar uma `String` bem grande contendo todos os *inserts*, eu faria assim:

```java
class Teste {
    private static final String SQL_INSERT =
        "INSERT INTO tabela (col_codigo, col_chave) VALUES ('X', 'Y');\n";

    public static String juntarTodasAsSQLs(String chave, String[] valores) {
        String a = SQL_INSERT.replace("X", chave);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(valores.length * (a.length() + 5));
        for (String valor : valores) {
            sb.append(SQL_INSERT.replace("Y", valor));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String chave = "999";
        String[] arrayOriginal = {"10", "20", "30", "40"};
        String resultado = juntarTodasAsSQLs(chave, arrayOriginal);
        System.out.println(resultado);
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```sql
INSERT INTO tabela (col_codigo, col_chave) VALUES ('X', '10');
INSERT INTO tabela (col_codigo, col_chave) VALUES ('X', '20');
INSERT INTO tabela (col_codigo, col_chave) VALUES ('X', '30');
INSERT INTO tabela (col_codigo, col_chave) VALUES ('X', '40');
```

[Veja aqui este exemplo funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/VgpQhD)

Mas se no seu problema, você só precisa da parte que está após o `VALUES` e ela deve necessariamente vir na forma de um `array` como resultado, então isso deve te ajudar:

```java
class Teste2 {

    public static String[] juntarTodasAsSQLs(String chave, String[] valores) {
        String[] novoArray = new String[valores.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
            novoArray[i] = "('" + chave + "', '" + valores[i] + "')";
        }
        return novoArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String chave = "999";
        String[] arrayOriginal = {"10", "20", "30", "40"};
        String[] resultados = juntarTodasAsSQLs(chave, arrayOriginal);

        for (String r : resultados) {
            System.out.println(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
('999', '10')
('999', '20')
('999', '30')
('999', '40')
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/NBncWu)

Comment: Oi Victor, vou tentar a sua segunda sugestão. Eu quase consegui utilizando o que segue: String[] array = ids;

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
 array[i] = "("+array[i]+","+codigoChave+")";
return Arrays.toString(array); como exemplo, o id é 83 e codigoChave170 e a saída ficou (8,170), (2,170) ... Muito obrigada pelo  retorno...

Comment: se seleciono 1 id ele separa os dígitos. ---> código utilizado: String chave = 170; String[] arrayOriginal = {82}; String[] resultados = juntarTodasAsSQLs(chave, arrayOriginal); String[] juntarTodasAsSQLs(String chave, String[] valores) { String[] novoArray = new String[valores.length]; for (int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {   novoArray[i] = "('" + chave + "', '" + valores[i] + "')";} return novoArray; } for (String r : resultados) { return r; \} // retornou somente ('8', '170')

Comment: @Fabi Poderia colocar esse código no Ideone ou então na sua pergunta para eu ver como é que está? Pois `String chave = 170;` não compila, então não sei como é que o seu código está de fato. Além disso, ver código-fonte em comentários é muito ruim, pois eles não têm a formatação apropriada e são muito limitados em tamanho.